# Gridview binding

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview inside a usercontrol. I am binding a List to the gridview and calling the DataBind() method. The datasource (here, List) is having around 500 records, but after binding its showing only 100 records.

I dont know, what I am missing ... where should I strike, everything seems prefect !

Plese F1 me .. !

Comment: @Amit Could you post some code

Comment: sorry, I wish I could, but cant.
I have to create some dummy code.

Comment: try setting `AllowPaging="True"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed something, e.g: setting page-size: 100 and then pager.visible=false

try to insert some snippet code

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time sir! I have got the prob. There was one javascript registered to modify the output on pageload. Thanks again.